# Content-Disposition not working

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to implement a CSV Export in a Google App Engine app based on Python and webapp2. 
In the post method of a RequestHandler I am trying...

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="exportedFile.csv"'
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
writer.writerow(['test1','test2','test3'])
```

I can't see any error in the Logs console but the Download popup is not depicted when the handler is requested

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
writer.write(['test1','test2','test3'])
```

to

```
writer.writerow(['test1','test2','test3'])
```

Also `application/csv` is not a proper content type.  Use `text/csv`.